# XAML ListView animation when removing and adding items too fast

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a UWP app and this contains a `ListView` with custom controls in it. I have created remove and undo functions. This is all being done nicely with default animations delivered by the .NET Framework. The problem is that when I remove an item and tap the undo button too fast, the item that was just removed is just instantly being added again, with no animation.

I have reconstructed this with a sample application that shows the same behavior.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private object removed;
    private int i;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        removed = List.Items[0];

        List.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List.Items.Add(removed);
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            List.Items.Insert(0, "Index " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

With the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Del" Tapped="Button_Tapped" />
    <Button Content="Readd" Tapped="Button_Tapped_1" />
    <ListView Name="List">

    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve the animation being played even when removing and readding items too fast?

Comment: You can implement the ICommand interface, it has an canexecute method That cyou can only alloq after the animation is over

Comment: That way I still have to implement this function myself, which I want to avoid.